# Arch linux build caffe error

Tags: linux, makefile, caffe, archlinux

I'm trying to build caffe from this repo: [caffe-textmaps](https://github.com/gogartom/caffe-textmaps)

But after I've fallow each step and I've install everything that I need I receive this error message:

```
    CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `test()':
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x3bc): undefined reference to `caffe::Caffe::singleton_'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x3ee): undefined reference to `caffe::Net<float>::Net(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, caffe::Phase)'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x150b): undefined reference to `caffe::Caffe::singleton_'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `train()':
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x218a): undefined reference to `caffe::Caffe::singleton_'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x231e): undefined reference to `caffe::Caffe::singleton_'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `time()':
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x2871): undefined reference to `caffe::Caffe::singleton_'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x28a4): undefined reference to `caffe::Net<float>::Net(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, caffe::Phase)'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x2cfd): undefined reference to `void caffe::caffe_gpu_dot<float>(int, float const*, float const*, float*)'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x3cdf): undefined reference to `caffe::Caffe::singleton_'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5caffe9SGDSolverIfEE[_ZTVN5caffe9SGDSolverIfEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `caffe::SGDSolver<float>::SnapshotSolverState(caffe::SolverState*)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5caffe9SGDSolverIfEE[_ZTVN5caffe9SGDSolverIfEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `caffe::SGDSolver<float>::RestoreSolverState(caffe::SolverState const&)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5caffe14NesterovSolverIfEE[_ZTVN5caffe14NesterovSolverIfEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `caffe::SGDSolver<float>::SnapshotSolverState(caffe::SolverState*)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5caffe14NesterovSolverIfEE[_ZTVN5caffe14NesterovSolverIfEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `caffe::SGDSolver<float>::RestoreSolverState(caffe::SolverState const&)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5caffe13AdaGradSolverIfEE[_ZTVN5caffe13AdaGradSolverIfEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `caffe::SGDSolver<float>::SnapshotSolverState(caffe::SolverState*)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5caffe13AdaGradSolverIfEE[_ZTVN5caffe13AdaGradSolverIfEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `caffe::SGDSolver<float>::RestoreSolverState(caffe::SolverState const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:562: .build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
```

Could anyone of you give me some advice how can I fix this problem?

Comment: First -- is this a clean tree? If you have object files compiled with a different ABI, that's a common cause of link-time errors. Running `make distclean` and starting from the beginning is a good place to start when first seeing this issue.

Comment: I can not do that... `make: *** No rule to make target 'distclean'.  Stop.
`

Comment: Replace with whatever the appropriate target is called for your makefile. `distclean` is the generic name used for projects that use GNU Autotools to generate their makefiles. I'm not there to read your project's makefile -- you are; pick whatever name is used for the most aggressive `clean`-analog target.

Comment: Yeh well, I did this already and it's exactly the same. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Find the source file that contains the code in question, and use `nm` to list the symbols in the object file created from its compilation. Note that templates aren't instantiated at definition time, so you can't just look for the definition of `SGDSolver` -- you need to find the `SDGSolver<float>` template being used. If you can't find that anywhere, then perhaps the code requires an explicit instantiation.